# Monitor a socket connection

Tags: python

I have a socket connection which I want to monitor, it recevies market data with high burst.

```
while 1:
    socket.recv()        
    print('data recevied')
```

The while loop should only execute print, once in sixty seconds.

Comment: but what if at that particular time, socket is receiving nothing so it won't be executed while socket might be functioning properly.

Comment: What do you want to happen in this case? Please be more specific about your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

last = datetime.now()
while 1:
    socket.recv()
    if (datetime.now() - last).seconds >= 60:
      print("data received")
      last = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want some kind of asynchronous processing here: on one hand you want to continuously receive data, on the other hand you want to display a message every 60 seconds.

So threading would be my first idea: foreground display messages while background receives.

```
def recv_loop(socket, end_cond):
    while True:
        socket.recv(1024)
    # assuming something ends above loop
    end_cond[0] = True

end = False
recv_thr = threading.Thread(target = recv_loop, args = (socket,[end]), daemon = True)
recv_thr.start()
while not end:
    time.sleep(60)
    print('data received')
```

You haven't show any interesting data in the message, so I haven't either. But as all global variables are shared, it would be trivial to display for example the number of bytes received since last message

Alternatively, you could use `select.select` because it gives you a timeout. So you change threading for a more complex timeout processing.

```
last = datetime.datetime.now()
while True:
    timeout = (datetime.datetime.now() - last).seconds + 60
    if timeout <= 0:
        last = datetime.datetime.now()
        print("data received")
    rl, _, _ = select.select([socket], [], [], timeout)
    if (len(rl) > 0):
        sockect.recv(1024)
```

Comment: your print('data received') while loop is independent of recv_thr it will keep on printing even if recv_thr thread exists.

Comment: You failed to say how the receiving thread should exit. Anyway it is trivial to add state variables. See my edit...